# Change keys of nested json in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, nested, key

i have a json object (its the following) :

```
{
  perspective_camera: {
    camera_view_point: { 
      x: -2.37,
      y: 26.12, 
      z: 18.97 
    },
    camera_direction: {
      x: 0.5573409184967458,
      y: -0.622517217811208,
      z: -0.5494027794776767
    },
    camera_up_vector: { 
      x: 0.36, 
      y: -0.4, 
      z: 0.83 
    },
    field_of_view: 60
  },
  components: {
    visibility: {
      view_setup_hints: {
        sv: true,
        sb: true,
        ov: true
      },
      exceptions: {},
      default_visibility: true
  },
  coloring: [],
  selection: []
 }
}
```

and what i want to do is changing the case of the keys from snake_case to PascalCase, i tried doing it recursively, but the problem with my code, it doesn't handle parent child relationship

here is the code i wrote :

```
function testRecurs(values, ParentComp = null) {
/* THIS FUNCTION NEEDS PARENT HANDELING IT RECOGNIZE OBJECTS FROM PRIMITIVE VALUE BUT ITS 
DOESN'T RESPECT THE PARENT CHILD RELATIONSHIP */
let NewJsonObj = {}
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(values)) {
  if (typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number' || typeof value === 'boolean' || 
      typeof value === null || typeof value === undefined) {
       //console.log(snake2Pascal(key), " : ", value)
       NewJsonObj[snake2Pascal(key)] = value
  } else {
       //console.log(snake2Pascal(key), " : ", typeof value)
       NewJsonObj[ParentComp] = ""
       testRecurs(value,snake2Pascal(key))
  }
}
//console.log(NewJsonObj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution for the problem, the answer is the following :

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(values)) {
  values[snake2Pascal(key)] = value
  //when the value is not an object
  if (typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number' || typeof value === 'boolean' || typeof value === null || typeof value === undefined) {
    delete values[key]
  } else { //when the value is an object
    delete values[key]
    ChangeKeyCase(value)
  }
}
```

i know it might be 80% good, i mean maybe there is adjustements to be more efficient and performant, so anysuggestions to upgrade is welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
const snakeToCamel = (str) => str.replace(
  /([_][a-z])/g,
  (group) => group.toUpperCase()
    .replace('_', '')
)

const nestedRename = object => {
  if (typeof object === 'object' && !Array.isArray(object)) {
    return (Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) =>
        [snakeToCamel(key), nestedRename(value)]
      )
    ))
  } else {
    return object
  }
}
```

and just call `nestedRename` function.